# How can I set the clock to 24 hour mode in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm Finnish but I want to use my phone in English (US). I cannot find a 24 hour clock setting. In Ubuntu desktop this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing language from English US to another English (there are a lot of them). I changed from "English US" to "English Canada" to display temperatures in Celsius.

Comment: Thanks, "English Denmark" was the solution this time. I'll have to accept this as the answer despite it being just a hack :)

Comment: Here's a related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1392699

Answer (score 0):

as of 2023 (time flies)
you can edit /home/phablet/.pam_environment

leave

```
LANGUAGE=en_US
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

but set

```
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
```

save and reboot